# Null values won't appear as a result

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the types that type does not equal 'C'. result need to include null types also.here is my query.

```
SELECT
(SELECT d.clm_name FROM CORPINFO.TBLCLIENTMAIN d WHERE 
d.clm_code=a.strice_companycode) AS CurrentInsuraceCompany
FROM leaseinfo.TRN_ICE_INSURANCECOVERNOTEENTR a
WHERE a.strice_conno='HQLE152609770'
AND a.strice_instype!='C';
```

In my table, i have 4 values to strice_instype.
'C'
'E'
'N'
and Null

now I need to get records that not equal 'C'.

It gets the results E and N. but it won't show the rows that contains null as strice_instype.

Comment: Try using `OR a.strice_instype IS NULL`?

Comment: tried already. but it returns duplicate columns. the result should return only 1 row for this 'HQLE152609770' number. it only contains type C  and null. so result should be 1 row. but if I use is null, it returns large number of columns

Comment: Looks like you are mixing up columns and rows. In the question you said that you are getting result for E and N and in the comment you are saying 1 row.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

`AND (a.strice_instype IS NULL OR a.strice_instype != 'C')`

Option 2:

`AND NVL(a.strice_instype,'NotC') != 'C'`

Comment: How does (1) not work? Do note the brackets, they're quite important.

Comment: @Didu: option 1 does exactly the same thing as option 2

Comment: but option 1 gives me a null result